# limit number of added markers on gmap v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Using google map v3 and a small jquery plugin, i have made a page for users, to add points/markers on google map.
So far this works perfectly.
Now, i need to improve this functionality and allow users to add multiple number of markers/points on the map. 
Each user will be limited to a specific number of points he can add.
This number is unique per user - so it must be variable.

The js code i use so far is this.

```
$("#my_map").gmap3({
    map:{
        options:{
            center:[start_lat, start_long],
            zoom: start_zoom,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions:  {   style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU    },
            navigationControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            streetViewControl: false
        },
        events:{                    
            click: function(map, event) // clicking on map adds a new marker
            {
                var lat = event.latLng.lat(), 
                    lng = event.latLng.lng();
                // save to form
                $("#map_lat").val(lat);
                $("#map_long").val(lng);
                $("#map_zoom").val( map.getZoom() );

                $(this).gmap3({
                    clear: { id: ["newTag"] }, // remove old/new tags (based on marker id value)
                    marker: { id: 'newTag', latLng: event.latLng } // add new marker on map
                });
            } // end click
        } // end event
    } // end map
});

map = $("#my_map").gmap3('get');
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

start_lat, start_long, start_zoom are parameters passed into the function.
map_lat, map_long, map_zoom are ids in the form of the page - clicking on map populate these fields.

Now, lets assume i want to allow only 2 markers to be added.
I can generate proper unique ids in the form to be populated.
I can pass another variable in the function to know the limit of markers.
But how do i modify the click events to limit them?

I hope this makes sense.


**EDIT:** I have managed to do what i, in a non-elegant way. I wonder if there is something more elegant?

```
// assuming var maxItems=2 (argument in function
                for (var i=0; i<=maxItems; i++)
                {
                    if ( $("#map_lat"+i).val()=='' || $("#map_long"+i).val()=='' || $("#map_zoom"+i).val()==''      )
                    {
                        // populate form fields
                        $("#map_lat"+i).val(lat);
                        $("#map_long"+i).val(lng);
                        $("#map_zoom"+i).val( map.getZoom() );

                        $(this).gmap3({
                            clear: { id: ["newTag"+i] }, // remove old/new tags (based on marker id value)
                            marker: { id: 'newTag'+i, latLng: event.latLng } // add new marker on map
                        }); 

                        break;
                    }


}
```

Comment: How do you want to set that limit? Is that stored somewhere? Database? Cookie? Session?

Comment: create an array of marker for each user and display only fixed number of markers.

Comment: @MrUpsidown. It will be an argument in my function

Comment: @gaurravv5. Not too fluent with marker management. I managed to do what i want with basic skills. Look at my edit.

Comment: I don't much get what you are trying to do with that `for` loop. I'd have global variables holding the max allowed markers and a counter. Each time the user creates a marker, increment the counter. In the click event, check that the counter is not greater than the max allowed value.

Comment: @MrUpsidown... since i dont get along with marker management very well, i use the for loop to check if my form fields are empty or not. If empty, i populate them with the marker data. As i said, not elegant.

Comment: We need to know more... What is the purpose of that form? How did you create the form fields? I don't get it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown. Each click on map will populate form fields with long/lat/zoom of marker. User will be able to save these and create a custom map with his own points on it. I didn't think this was relevant to my question. All i want to know is how to prevent user from clicking more than X times on the map (thus, prevent him from adding more than X markers)

Comment: As I said, I would increment a counter every time a marker is added. On click, check the counter against the maxItems `if (counter <= maxItems) ...`. Then instead of filling the form fields, just create them and add them to the DOM. (How did you do that btw? How many form fields are there at first?)

Answer (score 1):

you can create markers simply by the following way and manage separate arrays for user..

```
var markers = new Object();
function click_event(user_id)
{ 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:mycenter,
      title:infoName,
      id: count++
      // animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      });

    markers[user_id].push(marker);

    display_markers(user_id, limit);
}

function display_markers(user_id, limit)
{
    remove_markers(); //remove all previous markers from map
    for( var i = 0; i < limit ; i++ )
    {
        markers[user_id][i].setMap(map); //will set limited markers for particular user
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the user_id? This is javascript... Client side.

Comment: yes can be done without any user_id, just for easy understanding.

Comment: this code seems to work on pure google map. I dont know how to implement it to my code (i use gmap jquery plugin)

Comment: you must be using an api key for this, map simply refers to the map variable you are using, rest is pure javascript.

Comment: You will need an API key anyway.

Comment: Right. You don't *need* one but it's strongly recommended.